# SiteMesh or tiles

Tags: templates, tiles, sitemesh

In order to make our web pages with the same theme,we want to use some template,and we found apache tiles and sitemesh so far,but the tiles is not easy to work with,it have som learn curve,and the sitemesh team is not active any more,so I ask if you guys has other resoltion?

Our server side language is java,and use the struts2.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'd recommend SiteMesh if you must stick with Struts.  I've had success with it.

Better yet, try Spring web MVC and Velocity.  I think it's a better solution on both the client and server sides.

Comment: Using spring web mvc instead of struts2 and velocity instead of jsp?